# Select all except list and it's title

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this chunk of HTML-page

```
<div class="ProductDescriptionContainer">
<p>This handsome Clergy Shirt has a trim low neckband with two reinforced buttonholes, one at the front, one at the back, to align with Ziegler's Collarettes, Collars and Collar buttons. This clerical shirt also includes convertible cuffs which may be buttoned or used with cuff links, and a single breast pocket on a plain button front.&nbsp;All of Ziegler's neckband shirts are designed to be worn with a Parsons Brand Collar or under one of our Cleric-Collar Shirtfronts. Order Now! Neck Sizes Available: 15-20.5" Including Half Sizes Sleeve Lengths Available: Short &nbsp;/&nbsp;Clergy Shirt Colors: &nbsp;Black, White, Grey, Church Purple, Medium Blue, French Blue, Navy</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Clergy Shirt Details:&nbsp;</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Neck Sizes Available: 15-20.5" Including Half Sizes</li>
<li>Colors Available: Black, White, Grey, Church Purple, Medium Blue, French Blue, Navy</li>
<li>Sleeve Lengths Available: Short</li>
<li>Collar: Black Dress Neckband</li>
<li>Made in the U.S.A</li>
<li>Collars and Buttons sold Separately*</li>
<li><a title="CLICK HERE FOR OUR SELECTION OF COLLARS AND COLLARETTES" href="http://www.zieglers.com/church-goods/apparel-and-vestments/collars-and-rabats/">CLICK HERE FOR OUR SELECTION OF COLLARS &amp; COLLARETTES</a></li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: center;">*When buying a 2 ply collar or collarette for a neckband shirt it is best to order 1/2 size larger than the actual shirt you purchase for comfort.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>*Note- Church Purple, French Blue, Grey, Medium Blue, Navy and White are not standard colors. Availability and ship time will vary on these colors*</strong></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

And I need to select in HTML Agility pack all html except list and it's header right above it.
I tried to play with following-sibling and preceding-sibling combining with *not* but it wasn't successful

Comment: What you describe requires transformation, not selection, so you need XSLT, not just XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try LINQ, something like this:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(string);
var res = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Where(p => !p.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.Name.Equals("strong"));
```

This will select all p elements that don't have child `strong` element. I know it's not what you want but this will give you an idea. You can use `nextSibling` and look for `ul` as well

Comment: Filtering by `strong` is not correct but with `nextSibling` and `ul` is. I tried but  it appears that it's an #text and the `nextSibling.nextSibling` is ul that I'm searching, but it's trows and null reference exception when I'm tried to make this in `foreach` loop without LINQ(I'm pretty weak on that)

Comment: there's always a `#text` element in between, so you need to ignore it. something like `while(node.NextSibling.Name != "text)`

Comment: Doesn't understood now it should work with this code.